How to HTMLElement[] type from DOM?
In TypeScript I need to collect all  top level document of a page and using below code (the condition inside if is made simpler for brevity):
const getHTMLElement() : HTMLElement[] {
  const doc = document.body.children;
  const list : HTMLElement[] = [];
      for (let c of Array.from(doc)) {
          if (c.tagName === 'DIV' && c.textContent !== '') {
              list.push(c);
          }
      }
  console.log({list})
}


but it gives error on .push(c) line
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.

what is wrong here?
tried with querySelectorAll()
const getHTMLElement = (): HTMLElement[] {
  const doc = document.querySelectorAll('body');
  const list = [];
      for (let c of Array.from(doc)) {
          if (c.tagName === 'DIV' && c.textContent !== '') {
              list.push(c);
          }
      }
  console.log({list})
}

although this doesn't give any type error but here type of c is HTMLBodyElement which seems me incorrect
What is the right way to get list of HTMLElement[] type?
As per suggesion; usingas
const doc = document.querySelectorAll('body > *') as HTMLElement[];

throw another error
Conversion of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' to type 'HTMLElement[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 23 more.

Also below code works fine with no type error (using as inside push method):
const list = [];
const getHTMLElement= (): HTMLElement[] => {
  const doc = document.querySelectorAll('body > *');
  const list: HTMLElement[] =  [];
      for (let c of Array.from(doc)) {
          if (c.tagName === 'DIV' && c.textContent !== '') {
              list.push(c as HTMLElement);
          }
      }
  return list;
}

but is this correct way or we can fix something here?

I think you want querySelectorAll('div') if you want to select divs.

.children could be svg or other types

@GeneralGrievance i think they want top level divs

I want all not specific to div actually, code was just for braveity, there is different logic in if

@DanielA.White Ah, right. Missed that.

TypeScript can only guess the type of the element obtained through querySelector()  in very simple cases. In more complex cases, like yours, you have to type them explicitly, with as HTMLElement, for instance.

@DanielA.White using their solution throw another error. updated the question itself

use an array conversion first! to fix that - my answer highlights that

If you really want an array of top-level divs use
const topLevelDivs = [...(document.querySelectorAll('body > div'))] as HtmlElement[]; 
                  // ^ or use Array.from(...)

Then you can filter them out by text content.
const nonEmptyTopLevelDivs = topLevelDivs.filter(el => el.textContent !== '');

Based on your comment on all top-level children this should work


const topLevels = [...(document.querySelectorAll('body > *'))] as HTMLElement[];
const nonEmptyTopLevels = topLevels.filter(el => el.textContent !== '');
console.log(nonEmptyTopLevels);
<body>
<div>non empty</div>
<div></div>
<span>non empty span</span>
<span></span>
</body>




Thanks but I want all top level documents within body, not jist div but issue is with typings

so you can change the selector to body > *

using const doc = document.querySelectorAll('body > *') gives same typing error typing of doc is NodeList<Element>
